# mysql long sql always greater than 200ms. why not 100 or 300?

Tags: mysql

I use mysql with java.

The average query time is 1~10ms.

And I find some long sql, they always takes like 201ms,205ms,202ms.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the tables that you use, if you have a huge data so it is going to take time.
but check if you are using indexes on your tables, if not you can use it because it helps a lot.

for more details about you query you can write the word explain before the query and it gives you explanation for optimizing queries.